# $\epsilon-\delta$ proof about integration

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

[image]

**Stable:**
[image]

I have researched, convened with classmates, and read a few textbooks over the weekend. I am stumped and have no idea where to start (or finish). I know it pulls from real analysis, but that was so long ago.

Comment: Is this just a complicated way of saying that $|\int_0^1f-\int_0^1g|\leq ||f-g||$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$.

If $\|f-g\|<\epsilon$, then $\left|\int_0^1f(x)dx  -\int_0^1g(x)dx  \right| = \left|\int_0^1(f(x)-g(x))dx   \right|\leq \int_0^1 |f(x)-g(x)|dx$.

The last quantity is less than $\int_0^1 \|f-g\| dx =\|f-g\|\cdot (1-0) =\|f-g\| < \epsilon$.